# Can special relativity explain left hand Fleming rule and right hand grip rule?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

We know that magnetism is just about electrostatic and special relativity. We also know that there is a lot of traditional rules to determine the direction of current, magnetic field, force and motion. Can we just use only special relativity and electrostatic to determine all these direction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the traditional argument to derive Maxwell's equations from Special Relativity and Electrostatics already implements all of the direction dependences, for they are already built in Maxwell's equations themselves. These hand rules are needed for the fields to solve the differential equations.

However, notice that Special Relativity is not always a practical way of remembering the signs, since in many cases it is not practical (and sometimes not even possible) to solve an electrostatics problem and transforming it to the full problem you wanted to solve. For a straight wire, it might be helpful, but no similar argument is available for a loop of current.